# How to make a square box around times in css/php?

Tags: php, css, time

I am working on a website in which I want to make a square box around times.

The php code which I have used in order to pull off the times is:

```
{
echo date('l', strtotime($key)).":&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['start']."&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;".$value['end']."<br/> <br/>";      
}
```

The above php pulls off the following day and times:
[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that I can put the square boxes around times, something like this:

[image]

Comment: you mean textbox or just a display?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed Didn't get you ?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed I want to place  a square box around times.

Comment: @RinsadAhmed I think we need to add some inline html code but i am not sure how can we do it.

Comment: You should apply css and div for this. Can see some example here https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-radius3

Comment: @RinsadAhmed Any pointer how can we integrate in the php code ? sorry worked very less on php as mentioned before.

Comment: This is pretty much tabular data so consider using a table which will allow you to style the columns to meet your requirement.

Comment: Get the styling the way you want it first then worry about the PHP portion.

Comment: @Dave I have worked on tabular data before but I am not sure how I can integrate in the php code. I think we need to add some html there.

Comment: @flash check out the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has nothing to do with design. And you should definitely not use characters 
 (like `&nbsp;`) to create *spaces* / margins

Demo: https://www.tehplayground.com/WtTs8Yk0pRw8wHAu

**use CSS instead:**

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body {height:100%; font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}


.times {
  display: inline-flex;  /* act as inline */
  flex-flow: row wrap;   /* wrap into flex rows */
}

.times>* {
  flex: 1 0 25%;         /* 25%, so subdivision by 4 elements */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.times>*:nth-child(2n) { /* every second child element (time SPAN) */
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="times">

  <span>mon:</span>
  <span>09:00</span>
  <span>to</span>
  <span>21:00</span>

  <span>tue:</span>
  <span>09:00</span>
  <span>to</span>
  <span>21:00</span>

  <span>wed:</span>
  <span>09:00</span>
  <span>to</span>
  <span>21:00</span>

</div>
```

so inside your PHP foreach simply `echo` like:

```
echo '
  <span>'. date('l', strtotime($key)) .':</span>
  <span>'. $value['start'] .'</span>
  <span>to</span>
  <span>'. $value['end'] .'</span>
';
```

Comment: But how can we integrate this code ? Where should I be adding html ?

Comment: @flash added an example to my answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Bulijan Are we missing any period in echo ?

Comment: @flash had a misplaced `:` Fixed now.

Comment: Ok then using times class will be in effect because I can't see that in the echo code ?

Comment: C.Bulijan Checking

Comment: ok, I had a look. I can't see any closure of div tag like `</div>`

Comment: Which line number?

Comment: @flash Refresh this page and click again the link in my answer. PS: When you see something obvious missing - you're welcome to add it by your-self.

Comment: No no. Your code is very good. The reason why I was asking that because I think it is in that we mix html with php.

Comment: @flash PHP, when used for *View* purpose - it's here so we can mix it with HTML. It's absolutely normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178403/discussion-between-flash-and-roko-c-buljan).

Comment: Also notice that the above-presented CSS might not perfectly siut your design - you don't need to use flexbox, YOu can always assign classes to every `span` and style it in CSS accordingly. You can also additionally wrap every echo block into a parent `div` ... Hope you'll get it working the way you want.

Answer (score -1):

I have added the round-cornered box around the time values. Round cornered boxes were created using CSS class called box. Put this code in the header section of your page

```
<style>
.box{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

and change the php code as below

```
echo date('l', strtotime($key)).":&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class='box' >".$value['start']."</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class='box' >".$value['end']."</span><br/> <br/>";
```

Comment: added a picture. it is working fine for me. Do you get any error?

Comment: I am wondering if you can add html tag so that I can do styling in the css. It would be much easy in that way.

Comment: Like for example you can add some class I can style that class.